# testing for prime number with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to test if a number is a prime number using list comprehension. This is what ?I have done, but not getting the desired results.

```
number = 20
prime_number_test = [1 if number % i != 0 else 0 for i in range(2, 5)]
output = [0,1,0]
```

number 20 obviously isn't a prime number. Now if I have a known prime number to test like let say number 19

```
number = 19
prime_number_test = [1 if number % i != 0 else 0 for i in range(2, 5)]
output = [1,1,1]
```

Now my question is, why is the first code not all zeros, and what is the
best way to achieve this using a list comprehension that my results tells me this is a prime number

Comment: Clearly, `20%3 !=0`. That is why the first output is not all 0s.

Comment: A list comprehension is not a very good way to check for primes. You want to stop checking as soon as you find the first number that divides it, but a list comprehension has to test every number.

Comment: I hope that the new edited solution will give you a complete help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comprehension would give you a list of values, and you can use the `any` function. For example, here a list of `True` or `False` values is obtained:

```
number = 20
upper_limit = int(number ** 0.5)  # square root
prime_number_test = not any([number % i == 0 for i in range(2, 1 + upper_limit)])
print(prime_number_test)
```

The list returned by your comprehension is:

```
[True, False, True]
```

corresponding to division by 2, 3, and 4.

Then the `any` returns `True`, which the `not` then negates: 20 is not a prime number because it is divisible by 2 and 4.

Here you could also invert the test and do:

```
prime_number_test = all([number % i != 0 for i in range(2, 1 + upper_limit)])
```

Note the `!=` and the `all`.

However, in either case, it is more efficient (in time and memory) if you replace the square brackets with parentheses:

```
prime_number_test = not any((number % i == 0 for i in range(2, 1 + upper_limit)))
```

This similar looking expression uses a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), and instead of building up a list it will generate values on demand and the `any` will cause it to iterate as required and stop when the first match is found.

*(When using the generator as the sole argument of a function, as here, it is also permissible to omit the outer parentheses.)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. this clearly helped. Stack community is the best.Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

the above code show `[0,1,0]` because 20 is not divisible by 3 but is divisible by 2 and 4.
19 is not divisible by 2,3 or 4 so it has the output `[1,1,1]`
You can say that if there are 0 in output then the number is not prime.

you can use the following program to find primes.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))  
  
if num > 1:  
   for i in range(2,num):  
       if (num % i) == 0:  
           print(num,"is not a prime number")  
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)  
           break  
   else:  
       print(num,"is a prime number")  
         
else:  
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```